# GitHub Pages: This site can’t be reached

Tags: github-pages

I passed all the checks, but still, get this type of error. Any idea? Thanks.[image]
Here is my github: https://github.com/zechnegli/zecheng.github.io

Comment: Do you have an index.html in your root?

Comment: I do have, but this server is still not running.

Comment: Which site you are trying to reach? Remember that your page is published in http://zechnegli.github.io